# I can't umount a partition on Centos

Tags: linux, centos, hard-drive, mount

I had a drive fail of sorts. Now when I try to umount it is says the device is busy despite the device not being in /dev/

Any ideas how I can umount it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to "man umount" you should be able to use umount -f or umount -l to force the unmount (although -f is for NFS commands, so you'd want to try the -l on a local device; check your man pages to see that you have it supported on your kernel version)

What kind of failure did you have? You could try to see what processes are holding it open with "lsof" then kill those processes if that's what is causing the hold on the filesystem.